# postgreSQL - Select statement for many databases

Tags: database, postgresql, select

I would like to prepare **select** statement which will return results from many databases
(result will be concatenate of many select statement executed on different databases).
How I can do it in pgAdmin III?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you need to handle multiple databases ? I am asking that because you could use [schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html) instead. If you really need databases, then take a look at [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) module, which allows you to query remote databases from main connection.